# Input field offset

Tags: html, css

I have a contact form with some input field. One of the field is a menu to select the message subject. On mobile and narrow widths the menu displays fine, however on wide (desktop) displays it appears offset from the rest.

I've examined the css as best I can but can't seem to find the problem.

Can a fresh pair of eyes help please?

You can view the page here...

http://wearerain.co/test/ri-contact.html

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few CSS changes:

From the `.select-style` remove `overflow:hidden` and `border: 1px solid #d1d1d1`

and then from the `.select-style select` remove `border:none`

Comment: Magic! Thank you so much!.

Comment: Hi Charlene. I know this is a bit cheeky, but can you look at something else for me please (I can only post questions every 90 minutes!)

I have a page with a fixed header (navigation), with the content in sections below and a footer. 

For reasons I can't figure out, I can't scroll down the page.

http://wearerain.co/test/ri-expert.html

Comment: Hi @Tony sureee!

Comment: @Tony there is a overflow:hidden class in the body,html that is not allowing you to scroll through the page.

Comment: except that is breaks the parallax on the homepage :( 

Now there is whitespace below the footer. http://wearerain.co/test/s-index.html

Comment: and the background of the sticky header doesn't work :(

Comment: Delete this class     .wrapper-parallax {
    /* margin-bottom: 100vh; */
}

Comment: that looks like its fixed it. Thanks Charlene!

Comment: hmm - now the nav isn't sticking on the non-parallax pages
http://wearerain.co/test/ri-expert.html
http://wearerain.co/text/ri-work.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197953/discussion-between-tony-and-charlene-vas).